# ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFile': 'icon.png'"

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic-framework, app-store, application-loader

I am using Ionic to package my application.

```
 ionic package build ios --release --profile [myProfile]
```

This seems to be working fine.

When I try to submit using Application Loader I get this error.

> ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIconFile': 'icon.png'"

Comment: matt - the duplicate answer does not helped you please reply here, I reopen the question and we go for next step

Comment: The other answer requires Xcode to package. My question requires Ionic to package.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly the same error when uploading to test flight. My project is built with **Cordova**.

I solved this by **update the version of Cordova** to latest and rebuild.

Hopefully it will help.